# Updating python 2 code to python 3 code for googleads api

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api

I'm trying to use the google ads api with python 3 and I'm facing an issue with their generate_refresh_token.py file. The file has been updated for python 3 but I need to debug it as it still has some python 2 code in it. For example, print statements didn't have () in them and there was an instance of using raw_input() instead of input().

Anyway, I'm getting an error message that I can't figure out. Can someone please help me out here?

I've tried googling the solution but I'm a bit lost here.

The code starts from line 110 and ends at line 122:

```
print ('Access token: %s') % flow.credentials.token
print ('Refresh token: %s') % flow.credentials.refresh_token


if __name__ == '__main__':
  args = parser.parse_args()
  configured_scopes = [SCOPE]
  if not (any([args.client_id, DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID]) and
          any([args.client_secret, DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET])):
    raise AttributeError('No client_id or client_secret specified.')
  if args.additional_scopes:
    configured_scopes.extend(args.additional_scopes.replace(' ', '').split(','))
  main(args.client_id, args.client_secret, configured_scopes)
```

The code is supposed to throw out an access token that I can use but it's giving me this error:

```
Access token: %s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_refresh_token.py", line 122, in <module>
    main(args.client_id, args.client_secret, configured_scopes)
  File "generate_refresh_token.py", line 110, in main
    print ('Access token: %s') % flow.credentials.token
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I believe that this is also a python 2 vs python 3 problem and i would appreciate it if someone could help me out with this!

Comment: Let me know if i need to provide any additional information with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo with your parentheses. Print should be:

```
print('Access token: %s'% flow.credentials.token) 
print('Refresh token: %s' % flow.credentials.refresh_token)
```

To be safe use format:

```
print('Access token: {}'.format(flow.credentials.token))
print('Refresh token: {}'.format(flow.credentials.refresh_token))
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the print statements.

```
print ('Access token: {}'.format(flow.credentials.token))
print ('Refresh token: {}'.format(flow.credentials.refresh_token))
```